# Create Site Policy in SharePoitn Online with PowerShell/CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-powershell, office-dev-pnp

I was researching for add/edit/delete Site Policy in SharePoint Online with PowerShell/REST but with no luck.

Is it possible with SharePoint Online with PowerShell/CSOM?

Answer (score 1):

CSOM for SharePoint online contains the [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InformationPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj166937(v%3Doffice.15)) namespace which contains the API for handling the site policies.

You can use it by adding the reference to the `Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy.dll` and adding

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InformationPolicy;
```

to your class.

[ProjectPolicy.GetProjectPolicies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj163755(v%3Doffice.15)) method can be used to retreive all the defined policies.

Here's simple c# code for listing all the policies defined on the site collection
(I'm assuming here that you have already connected to the site using the csom):

```
var policies = ProjectPolicy.GetProjectPolicies(context, web);
context.Load(policies);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//For example the policies.Count property would give you the count of the defined policies. 
//This should list all the policies names:
foreach(var p in policies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

[ProjectPolicy.ApplyProjectPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj165640(v%3Doffice.15)) method can be used for applying the policy to the appropriate site.

**EDIT** (based on the OP's comment):
Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to create site policies using the API.
Here's the [PnP Github page](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.InformationManagement) which states this.

Comment: Thanks, @Damjan. When I connected to Content Type Hub Site I was able to see all policies but I do not see any API to Add/Edit/Delete Policy. I would really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: That is currently not possible. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Damjan. One last question, is there RestAPI available to fetch all site policy or CSOM is the only option?

Comment: No, unfortunately the Rest API for fetching the policies doesn't seem to exist, so the CSOM is currently your only option there.